# Get the cronjob api used for all cronjobs in all namespaces kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, cron, azure-aks

I want to view the api version used in all cronjobs in all namespaces in my cluster. Recently updated the cronjob api to latest and wanted to verify that all cronjobs are using the new api.

Comment: any update on this ? feel free to update the status of question if any of below answer resolves you issues or do share your solution if manage to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **kuebectl** command to list all the cronjobs in all namespaces

```
kubectl get cronjobs -o=custom-columns=NAME:.metadata.name,API-version:.apiVersion -A
```

it will create two column for you like

```
NAME                                       API-version
oer                                         batch/v1
ABC                                         batch/v1
xyz                                         batch/v1
sync-cron                                   batch/v1
log-cleanup                                 batch/v1
check-passwords                             batch/v1
```